Why was Muffet II portrayed by a chimpanzee?
In the 1978 TV show Battlestar Galactica, the movie/pilot introduces a character named Boxey who has a pet "daggit" named Muffet, portrayed by a dog, as seen here:

Muffet is killed by falling debris during the Cylon attack on Caprica. As the survivor fleet embarks on its journey to find Earth, Boxey is presented with a cybernetic dagget named Muffet II to ease his grief. Muffet II is portrayed by a chimpanzee in a full-body costume as seen here:

What was the production rationale for dressing a chimp in a costume to portray a cybernetic dog? What made this the preferred option, given that there must have been other possibilities at least suggested? Would this not have presented problems on-set, making this is in hind-sight at least, not the best idea?


Update: A more-or-less contemporaneous show operating on a much smaller budget (Doctor Who) went a slightly different way with its on-screen representation of a cybernetic dog (K-9, first appeared in 1977):


For the publicity. Kids love monkeys even more than they love dogs.

I'd be curious to know what other possibilities you think existed? The technological advances over the last 40 years have been breathtaking and it's easy to forget (or not even know if you're young enough) just how far we've come. CGI wouldn't be capable of doing it for decades. Animatronics were seriously limited. Robotics as a science was just getting going. I suppose another child or a little person - but humans need to be paid where animals are comparatively cheap. While I'm curious to see an authoritative answer, I believe the possibilities were a lot fewer than you think.

@JBH - I'm guessing OP means "Why not just stick the same dog in a robot suit"

Because dogs don't have semi-humanoid movements which the character required. Additionally their capacity for learning complex movements is significantly less than a chimpanzee.

@Paulie_D - That's certainly one argument. The obvious alternative position is that chimps are notoriously difficult to train, temperamental, prone to fits of violence, easily tired from filming and substantially more expensive in comparison to a dog.

@Paulie_D interesting, point. I was looking for a more authoritative rather than speculative answer - what did the production team actually consider that ultimately led them to what was done.

Because if he'd been portrayed by an elephant, the suit wouldn't have fit over his trunk.

I was at a Battlestar Galactica convention and I saw a "Muttet II" fairly close up.  I don't know what person, or animal, or machine  made the suit move, but it seemed as good as in the tv show.   So it either the chimp from the show or some other method which seemed to work about as well.

@M.A.Golding Doubtful it would have been a costumed chimp considering the environment of a convention and the potential for a chimp to "go rogue" at any moment. TV sets are busy/chaotic places as it is, but one might imagine that for a scene requiring a specific performance from an animal, things might be leaned down and calmed down to minimize distraction/provocation. That's not going to happen on a convention floor.

This behind the scenes / retrospective indicates that they decided that the chimpanzee was the most trainable option available.
They often had "stunts" required to be learned at short notice (2-3 days) which is probably not attainable with another animal.



As indicated in the comments...

chimps are notoriously difficult to train, temperamental, prone to fits of violence, easily tired from filming and substantially more expensive in comparison to a dog.

This video confirms that is indeed true causing some disruption and delay to filming.

As I understand the statements made in that video, "Evie" was both unusual for a chimp in that she could be quickly/readily trained up on a new stunt, but also typical for a chimp in being temperamental and unpredictable when the cameras were rolling. In her case, it seems to be an open question as to whether her typical chimp-ness outweighed her trainability.
